# Is there any function to retrieve Counters values?

Tags: python, python-3.x

That is what I have:

```
In:  u = np.random.choice(['Male','Female'], len(null_Gender), p = P_Gender)
In:  Counter(u)
Out: Counter({'Female': 115730, 'Male': 357627})
```

I would like to extract the count values, without writing them manually.

Comment: Removing `pandas` tag as it is irrelevant here.

Answer (score 1):

`collections.Counter` is a subclass of `dict`, so you can just call `values`

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter({'Female': 115730, 'Male': 357627})
print(list(c.values()))
>>> [357627, 115730]
```

Comment: Ok ! Thank. It works